# I get error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, nlp, series, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have 2 rows, first and second,with word in each column (each row is basically a text).
| row      |      |     |     |
| -------- | ---- |---- |---- |
| First    | word1|word2 |word3....
| Second   | word1|word2  |word3....

I want to see similarity. I don't have the frequency but just the words, but from what I know this algorithm also gives me the frequencies. The problem that it gives me this error:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
 last)
 <ipython-input-11-1000d05112e2> in <module>
  28     return result
   29 
---> 30 get_jaccard_sim(first, second)
  31 

  <ipython-input-11-1000d05112e2> in get_jaccard_sim(first, second)
   22 
   23 def get_jaccard_sim(first, second):
  ---> 24     a = set(first.split())
   25     b = set(second.split())
   26     c = a.intersection(b)

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in 
  __getattr__(self, name)
   5128             if 
 self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  5129                 return self[name]
-> 5130             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
 5131 
 5132     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I want to split each of the words and get frequencies and similarity between each of the words in the text. Also I tried to get ride of the NAN completely, but it didn't work out. I still see NANs when I print the columns)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score

data = pd.read_csv("articles of Shoshana Solomon2.csv", index_col ="article_id")


# retrieving row by loc method
first = data.iloc[2]
second = data.iloc[3]
#third = data.iloc[4]
#fourth=data.iloc[5]
list_no_nan=[first,second]
print(list_no_nan)

#list1 = [x for x in list_no_nan if str(list_no_nan) != 'nan']
#print(list1)


def get_jaccard_sim(first, second): 
  a = set(first.split()) 
  b = set(second.split())
  c = a.intersection(b)
  result=float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))
return result

get_jaccard_sim(first, second)
```

What to fix here? Thank you!

Comment: Please, always show more than a line of your Traceback

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO added

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. `first` is a row in the dataframe expressed by a Series object. Are all of the columns strings and you want to split them? Then `first.str.split()`. Broadcast operations like split are more often done on columns than rows. But I didn't figure out what your intent is, so it may be right.

Comment: @tdelaney
  split the words and put them into set

Answer (score 2):

`first` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` object built from a single row of the dataframe. I think your question is about how to split the words in these columns and create a set. String operations on a `Series` are available through the `.str` attribute. That will create a new series holding lists of split text. You can then iterate those to build the set. `itertools` has a handy method for that.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import itertools
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["one and"], "B":["two and and and"], "C":["three"]})
>>> first = df.iloc[0]
>>> print(first)
A            one and
B    two and and and
C              three
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> split = first.str.split()
>>> print(split)
A              [one, and]
B    [two, and, and, and]
C                 [three]
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> final = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(split))
>>> print(final)
{'three', 'and', 'one', 'two'}
```